# Resolving placeholder within @PropertySource

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to make a configuration class that will load application properties from a file using the @PropertySource annotation, but the PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer doesnt seem to set the location received from the annotation.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.just.a.test")
@PropertySources({
    @PropertySource(value="file:C:\\tmp\\1.cfg" 
            , ignoreResourceNotFound=true)
})
public class TestConfig {
    @Value("${just.a.string}")
    String justAString;


    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
       return propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
    }
}
```

the application property file is :

```
just.a.string=DOH
```

and im receiving the following exception :

> ....
>       Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'just.a.string' in string value "${just.a.string}"
>           at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:174)
>           at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:126)
>           at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:204)
>           at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:178)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer$2.resolveStringValue(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:175)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveEmbeddedValue(AbstractBeanFactory.java:801)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
>           ... 15 more

how ever, if i am setting the location using the PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer bean, everything works fine.

```
@Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.setLocation(new FileSystemResource("c:\\tmp\\1.cfg"));
       return propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
    }
```

i am using Spring 4.1.6-RELEASE , and jdk 8.05.

thanks in advance.

**UPDATE 1**

as sivaprasadreddy.k mentioned. the code above does work fine, i forgot that in my original code i am retrieving the file out of a JVM param using the -

```
@PropertySource(value="file:#{systemProperties['config.path']}"
```

and passing a jvm param of:

```
-Dconfig.path=C:\\tmp\\1.cfg
```

@Sotirios - im just using an AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Class) like so -

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 
new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(TestConfig.class);
 }
```

**UPDATE 2**

basically what im trying to achieve is this:

1) load a property file using a jvm param which its name defined as a const

a) if the file is found then proceed

b) else if a default file path which defined as a const exists then proceed

c) else proceed.

2) try to resolve @Value using a property which its name is defined as a const

a) if found proceed

b) else load a default value using a const.

sorry for the spaces. something is wrong with the editor.

Comment: Can you show how you load your `TestConfig`?

Comment: Can you remove the `ignoreResourceNotFound=true` and see if tries to load the resource?

Comment: I took your code snippets and tested with Spring-4.1.6 and JDK 8 and is working fine. It is resolving and printing "DOH" if I output justAString value.

Comment: @Sotirios - im just using an AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Class) like so -                                                                                                     public static void main(String[] args) {
     new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(TestConfig.class);
    }

Comment: This works for me. Can you provide a complete and reproducible example that doesn't?

Comment: @minion - i can test without it , but i need it to be set as true as i want it later to rely on default value if the property isnt found.

Comment: @sivaprasadreddy.k - you are absolutely right. in my original code i use a jvm param to receive the file path like so -                                            @PropertySource(value="file:#{systemProperties['config.path']}"               and passing a jvm param with -Dconfig.path="c:\\tmp\\1.cfg

Comment: I recommend you edit your question to put the issue of the placeholder first. We can then clean up these comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering your edit

```
@PropertySource(value="file:#{systemProperties['config.path']}"
```

you have to first realize that the `@Configuration` class (and its annotations) is parsed and processed before the `@Bean` declared inside it. In other words, your `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfig` (which does resolution of `#{..}` placeholders) has not been registered by the time Spring has processed the `@PropertySource` annotation. It's not available.

Instead, Spring can perform a subset of the behavior provided by a `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfig`, only the `${..}` placeholders. ([See the javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html).) And it can only use the property sources already registered with your `ApplicationContext`'s `Environment`. In your examples, there are (should be) only two sources, the system properties and system environment.

The notation

```
systemProperties['config.path']
```

states: give me the value of the property `config.path` in the property source named `systemProperties`. I'm not sure in which order Spring checks the property sources named above, but if you know that only your system properties (and not the environment) has a `config.path` property, you can simply use

```
@PropertySources(value = { @PropertySource(value = "file:${config.path}") })
```

Comment: Thanks Sotirios. using the ${..} i can now successfully load the file into the PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfig and resolve the value ${just.a.string}. i see the file is in the PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfig.environment.propertySources=[systemProperties,systemEnvironment,URL [file:C://tmp//1.cfg]]} how ever i still unable to resolve the value using #{..} .

Comment: Spring does not handle placeholders that start with `#{` in `@PropertySource` values.

Comment: i mean in @Value i still cant load a property that i loaded using @PropertySource(${config.path})

Comment: @Value("#{systemProperties['just.a.string']}") = null ,

Comment: @TalBenShabtay Do you have a property called `just.a.string` in your System properties? Or is it in the properties file you loaded?

Comment: only in the file. i thought it was being loaded to the SystemProperties.

Comment: @TalBenShabtay No, it gets loaded in the property sources in the `Environment`. But it seems you can't access them directly by name.

Comment: any idea how do i proceed with the psudo i wrote in update 2 ?

Comment: @TalBenShabtay You won't be able to do it with the default `@Configuration`, `@PropertySources`, `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`, and `@Value` behavior. It's quite the custom requirement. You'll have to write your own property loading logic, with appropriate fallbacks.

Comment: i see, well thats unfortunate. Thanks Sotirios for your help, i will have to revise my goals in configuration loading for my app then.

Answer (score -1):

Trying adding @TestPropertySource(properties = {"targetEnv = test"})
ex. whichever env variable you want to inject.

Comment: Don't hijack a question, especially not with an answer that doesn't make sense. `@TestPropertySource` is only feasible in test classes and for Spring Boot not for regular Spring.