# How do i access -D parameter from Spring Java Config?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

i'm looking into migrating my Spring XML config into Java. I'm having some trouble with my PlaceHolderConfigurer.

In XML i have "locations set up as

```
<property name="locations">
        <list>
            ...
            <value>file:////${project.home}/conf/jdbc.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
```

, where "project.home" is a parameter i've set with "-Dproject.home=...."

Now, i'm not sure how to do this with Java, since i can't just use

```
new FileSystemResource("file:////${project.home}/conf/jdbc.properties"),
```

So, if i want to use PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.setLocations with a system.property, how do i do that? Pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A combination of **context:property-placeholder** and **@Value** annotation can be used for injecting a set of properties into Spring Beans easily.

---

**Here is the 3-step procedure to accomplish this:**

**Step 1:**  Define all the required properties inside a ***'key=value'*** type file

> application.properties

**Step 2:**  Specify the location of application.properties file in the bean config, using **property-placeholder**

**Step 3:**  Use **@Value** annotation in Java program to fetch properties.

---

**Here are the code snippets for a working example:**

**Step 1:**  Define properties in 'key=value' format

```
# File name: application.properties

db.schema=my_schema
db.host=abc.xyz.com:3306
db.table=my_table
```

**Step 2:** Mention the location of properties file using property-placeholder

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" ...>

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties"/>

    <!-- other content -->
</beans>
```

**Step 3:**  Fetch properties using @Value annotation

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;


public class MyProgram {

    @Value("${db.host}")
    private String dbHost;

    @Value("${db.schema}")
    private String dbSchema;

    @Value("${db.table}")
    private String dbTable;

    @Override
    public void showConfig() {
        System.out.println("DB Host = " + dbSchema);
        System.out.println("DB Schema = " + dbSchema);
        System.out.println("DB Table = " + dbSchema);
    }
}
```

**Output of call to showConfig()**

```
DB Host = abc.xyz.com:3306
DB Schema =  my_schema
DB Table = my_table
```

**More information:**

https://memorynotfound.com/load-properties-spring-property-placeholder/

https://memorynotfound.com/loading-property-system-property-spring-value/

https://mkyong.com/spring/spring-propertysources-example/

Answer (score 0):

System.getProperty will give you the property set using -D java option

Comment: Right, but then i'd have to concatenate together the file url string manually in my java config class, i was hoping  there was any way to do it kind of like i did in xml.

Comment: what's wrong with concatenation? if you want you can also use String.format() to avoid string concat. I dont think java has any expression to replace values from JVM arguments.

Comment: If you are using Spring easier way to do this would be using @Value annotation.. it can read value from JVM args a also

 @Value("${spring.project.home}/abc.properties")
 private String projectHome ;

Answer (score 0):

Since you are attempting to call `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.setLocations()` with custom locations you probably should use [`@PropertySource`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html) annotation.

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value="file://#{systemProperties['project.home']}/conf/jdbc.properties")
public class MyConfig {

}
```

You can also configure the `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` bean if you need more fine grained control e.g. if your location uses patterns. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14392570/1602555) for more details.

Comment: But i don't want to hard-code the path to the project home in java, i want to set it with a jvm parameter when the program starts. I want the "classpath:....." to come from the system property.

Comment: Updated with `#{systemProperties}` syntax as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30785083/1602555)